# iOS how can I package reusable code in a reusable UI widget? Like a heavily modified text widget?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

iOS how can I package reusable code in a reusable UI widget?  Like a heavily modified text widget?

I built a UITextView that has a lot of custom functionality specific to my application (hits webserver for some special macro features, has special autocomplete dictionary, etc...)

I want to reuse this special text entry in multiple screens on my iOS application.  How can I neatly package this code up so it can easily be used as simply as a UITextView can be reused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a class that will have UITextView as a super class and this class will also be the place for implementing your functions to support the custom functionality and further your class will be used directly instead UITextView for availing of the custom functionality .

Comment: How do you use that new class directly?

Comment: Exactly the same way as you use 'UITextView' because your class will inherits properties from 'UITextView' ..

Comment: How would I add one of these new custom widgets via UIBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

You put the `@interface` block in a .h file and the `@implementation` block in a .m file. Then in any file you want to use it in, `#import` the .h file at the top (using double-quotes, not angle-brackets).

Comment: How do you replace the UIWidget for a textview with this new class?

Comment: What exactly is a "UIWidget"?

Comment: By UIWidget I meant something that could be put in UIBuilder.  How do you package UI design and code functionally so it can be reused as widgets from UIBuilder?

Comment: Ah, you should have asked that in the first place then. If you don't need anything beyond new IBOutlets, you can just pull it in from the library. Otherwise, in XCode 3 you can write an IBPlugin; unfortunately, IBPlugins are apparently [no longer supported in XCode 4](http://xcodebook.com/2011/03/no-interface-builder-plugin-support-in-xcode-4/).